# How to save and retrieve a list of custom objects with SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm making a Flutter app for fuel expenses tracking. I have a simple object:

```
class Entry {
  double _fuel;
  double _money;
  double _distance;

  Entry(this._fuel, this._money, this.distance);

  Entry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Entry (json['fuel'], json['money'], json['distance']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'fuel':_fuel, 'money':_money, 'distance':_distance};
}
```

Whenever I refill my tank I want to make a new entry and to keep all of them virtually forever. In the app I have a `List<Entry> entries`, but I couldn't find a way to save that list in `SharedPreferences`. There is only a method which accepts a list of Strings. Should I create a new `List<String>` by iterating through my `List<Entries>` and serializing each entry, and then saving that list to the `SharedPreferences` or is there an easier way? And when I want to read from `SharedPreferences`, how can I recreate my list?

Update: Of course, I also need to be able to delete a particular entry from the list.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192099/create-json-arrays-and-list-with-sharedpreferences/60237867#60237867

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Saving them as `List<String>` is a viable option indeed, and the other option I can think of is to serialize the whole list as json using `json.encode()` method and save it as a string in SharedPreferences, then retrieve and deserialize them and iterate over them to turn them into your custom object again.

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
List<Entry> entries = // insert your objects here ;
final String entriesJson = json.encode(entries.map((entry) => entry.toJson()).toList());
prefs.setString('entries', entriesJson);
final String savedEntriesJson = prefs.getString('entries);
final List<dynamic> entriesDeserialized = json.decode(savedEntriesJson);
List<Entry> deserializedEntries = entriesDeserialized.map((json) => Entry.fromJson(json)).toList();
```

- To remove a particular key (with its value) from SharedPreferences simply use the `remove(key)` method, or if you are going to use the same key, you can set the key with a new value and it will override the previous value.
- To remove a particular item from your `List<Entry>` you can use either the `remove(entry)` method of the `List class` if you can pass the item, or remove an item depending on a certain condition using the `removeWhere((entry) => entry.distance > 500)` for example.

Hope that helped.

Comment: This approach gives me an error `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'` when it tries to do `json.decode(savedEntriesJson);`

Comment: You can cast the result of `json.decode(savedEntriesJson)` `as List<Map<String, dynamic>>` or the type of entriesDeserialized `List<dynamic>` .. I will update the answer with that bit and also reply to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

For adding `entry` you do not need to serialize all entries, just use `getStringList` of `SharedPreferences` and add `json string` of your `entry` to string list, and save again

```
  var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List<String> entriesStr = sharedPreferences.getStringList(KEY);
  entriesStr.add(jsonEncode(entryToAdd.toJson()));
  sharedPreferences.setStringList(KEY, entriesStr);
```

Comment: Maybe an option for you just put all your entry with `entry_prefix` and if you need all of your `entries`, so you can use method getKeys() and after filter keys of all your `entries`

Comment: Just an additional question - how would I then remove a particular entry somewhere from the middle of the list and save the new state? I'll also update the original question.