# how to persist a list of custom objects in flutter with shared preferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i want to persist a list that has custom objects and i even wrote method for serializing and de-serializing it but i don't know how to use it with `SharedPreferences` and `FutureBuilder`

here is the custom object:

```
 class Fact {
  String factText;
  Color factColor;

  Fact(this.factText, this.factColor);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'factText': factText, 'factColor': factColor};

  Fact.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : factText = json['factText'],
        factColor = json['factColor'];
}
```

Comment: Same as [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192099/create-json-arrays-and-list-with-sharedpreferences/60237867#60237867](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192099/create-json-arrays-and-list-with-sharedpreferences/60237867#60237867)

Comment: and why dont you want to use a simple flat file instead?

Comment: @pskink isn't shared preferences sufficient enough?

Comment: shared preferences are implemented as xml files (at least on android) - so i dont think its the best for storing large amount of data

Comment: @pskink but i still need to do serialization right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a list inside shared_preference, then you can use the method [`setStringList()`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences/lib/shared_preferences.dart):

```
  /// Saves a list of strings [value] to persistent storage in the background.
  ///
  /// If [value] is null, this is equivalent to calling [remove()] on the [key].
  Future<bool> setStringList(String key, List<String> value) =>
      _setValue('StringList', key, value);
```

Comment: So I don't need to serialize my object?

Comment: you still need to use `fromjson`